# Install an old revision using Homebrew

Tags: git, homebrew

I am trying to install a formula using a commit that's a bit old.

When brew clones the repository, it seems it only downloads the two last commits, and it's impossible to ask for a revision older than that.

From the looks of the documentation, checking out old commits seems to be impossible using Homebrew. Is there a way to work around that ?

As an exemple, here's the 'head' property for the Formula:

```
  head 'git://anongit.kde.org/konsole.git', :revision => 'd8be35b5c7b93a324ed88f257785c2251f7cc964'
```

If you try cloning the repository yourself, you'll see that the revision does exist. But when homebrew does the clone, that revision isn't part of the tree.

Comment: As a lousy workaround, I went in /Library/Cache/Homebrew and made my own clone: this way, Homebrew uses my clown, with a full tree, and manages to checkout the revision that I specified in the Formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `brew edit FORMULA` to modify the url and sha to match the download that you are aiming for.